# Let $t$ be a transcendental number. Prove that the set $\{(a+bt) \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is not a number field.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Can I just pick a number in the set and then prove it's not constructible? Thx

Comment: What is your definition of "number field"?

Comment: "Constructible" could have technical meanings different from "algebraic" that you may want to be wary of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition a number field $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, so in particular, every element of a number field is algebraic, thus no transcendental number can be an element of a number field.

This is why number fields are also called **algebraic number fields**, since their elements are algebraic numbers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something worth noting: if $\{(a+bt) \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ with $t$ transcendental over $\Bbb Q$ *were* a field of *any* sort, then $(a + bt)^2 = a^2 + 2abt + t^2 = c + dt$ for some $c, d \in \Bbb Q$.  Then $t^2 + (2ab - d)t + (a^2 - c) = 0$; but this implies the the degree of $t$ over $\Bbb Q$ is at most $2$; $t$ *transcendental*? ***NOT!!!***

It appears this argument can be extended to cover the case $\{\sum_0^n a_i t^i \mid a_i \in \Bbb Q \}$ with $t$ transcendental as well, and maybe even applied to some other base fields.  Something to think about in your copious spare time!

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***